# Can I run a thread within a thread in java?

Tags: java, multithreading

In Java I have the necessity of implementing a class that extends Thread
within another similar class. Is that possible?

An example of what I am trying to do is the following (simplified) snippet:

```
// The first layer is a Thread
public class Consumer extends Thread {

    // Variables initialized correctly in the Creator
    private BufferManager BProducer = null;

    static class Mutex extends Object {}
    static private Mutex sharedMutex = null;


    public Consumer() {
        // Initialization of the thread
        sharedMutex = new Mutex();

        BProducer = new BProducer(sharedMutex);
        BProducer.start();
    }


    public void run() {

        int data = BProducer.getData();

        ///// .... other operations
    }


    ////// ...... some code

    // Also the second layer is a Thread
    private class BufferManager extends Thread {

        Mutex sharedMutex;
        int data;

        public BufferManager(Mutex sM) {
            sharedMutex = sM;
        }

        public int getData(Mutex sM) {
            int tempdata;
            synchronized(sharedMutex) {
                tempdata = data;
            }
            return tempdata;
        }

        public void run() {
            synchronized(sharedMutex) {
                data = getDataFromSource();
            }
            ///// .... other operations on the data
        }
    }
}
```

The second Thread is implemented directly inside the First one.
Moreover I'd like to know if implementing a Mutex like that will work.
If not, there's any better (standard) way to do it?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This is not Inception.

Comment: All threads are started by other threads, you don't have a choice.  Threads are for doing work as independently as possible.

Comment: Except for the Big-Bang which creates the very first Thread.  :-)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The `Thread` is not run 'within', but rather side-by-side.

So yes, you can start up another `Thread` to run side-by-side with your other two `Thread`'s.    As a matter of fact, any `Thread` can start another `Thread` (so long as the OS allows it).

Comment: Thank you @nicholas.hauschild .
So, the fact that is written within does not change the behavior of the Thread.
Is the shared Mutex of according to you?
Will it block the Consumer if the BufferManager locked it?

Comment: Well, I am not sure the code you have provided will compile (`new BProducer(sharedMutex)`?)  But I do think that your `Mutex` will allow your `Producer` and `Consumer` to lock properly.

Comment: See my answer for details, but I suggest that the declarations of the Mutex variables be final.

Comment: Thank you nicholas.hauschild you replied to my question.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, this should work and the shared Mutex should do it's job.  Out of paranoia, I'd make both the mutex declarations `final` to avoid any weird "escaping" issues.  e.g.

```
final Mutex sharedMutex;
```

One suggestion: maybe this is my style, but for code like this I seldom extend `Thread`.  Just implement `Runnable` instead.  IMO it's a bit less confusing (YMMV here).  Plus, when you start using advanced concurrency utilities like `Executor`, they deal with `Runnables`, not Threads.

Comment: +1 Excellent point about `Runnables`.  It would be difficult for `java.util.concurrent` classes to allow `Thread` pooling without using `Runnable`'s.

Comment: I've just seen your answer. By implementing Runnable you mean nesting the Runnables could work as well?